# How to test functions cdef'd in Cython?

Tags: python, unit-testing, cython

I have a .pyx file in which I define some functions, e.g.

```
cdef double foo(double a) nogil:
    return 3. * a
```

How could I unit test the behavior of such functions outside the pyx file? Since they are cdef'd, I am not able to simply import them...

Comment: How about writing a `def` or `cpdef` that calls `foo`?

Comment: Is there a good solution to this that does not involve cpdef?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To test `cdef`-fuctionality you need to write your tests in Cython. One could try to use `cpdef`-functions, however not all signatures can be used in this case (for example signatures using pointers like `int *`, `float *` and so on).

To access the cdef-functions you will need to "export" them via a pxd-file (the same can be done also for [cdef-functions of extension types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types) ):

```
#my_module.pyx:
cdef double foo(double a) nogil:
    return 3. * a

#my_module.pxd:
cdef double foo(double a) nogil
```

Now the functionality can be cimported and tested in a Cython-tester:

```
#test_my_module.pyx
cimport my_module

def test_foo():
    assert my_module.foo(2.0)==6.0
    print("test ok")

test_foo()
```

And now

```
>>> cythonize -i my_module.pyx
>>> cythonize -i test_my_module.pyx 
>>> python -c "import test_my_module"
test ok
```

Where to go from there depends on your testing infrastructure.

---

For example if you use `unittest`-module, then you could use pyximport to cythonize/load the test-module inspect it and convert all test cases into `unittest`-test cases or use `unittest` directly in your cython code (probably a better solution).

Here is a proof of concept for `unittest`:

```
#test_my_module.pyx
cimport my_module
import unittest

class CyTester(unittest.TestCase): 
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertEqual(my_module.foo(2.0),6.0)
```

Now we only need to translate and to import it in pure python to be able to `unittest` it:

```
#test_cy.py 
import pyximport;
pyximport.install(setup_args = {"script_args" : ["--force"]},
                  language_level=3)

# now drag CyTester into the global namespace, 
# so tests can be discovered by unittest
from test_my_module import *
```

And now:

```
>>> python -m unittest test_cy.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Btw, there is no need to cythonize pyx-modules explicitly - `pyximport` does it for us automatically.

**A word of warning:** `pyximport` caches cythonized c-files in `~/.pyxbld` (or similar on other OSes) and as long as `test_my_module.pyx` has not changed the extension isn't rebuild, even if its depenencies where changed. This might be a problem (among others), when `my_module` changes and it leads to binary incompatibility (luckily python warns if this is the case).

By passing `setup_args = {"script_args" : ["--force"]}` we force a rebuild.

Another option is to delete the cached-files (one could use a temporary directory, for example created with [`tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory),  via [`pyximport.install(build_dir=...)`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#arguments)), which has the advantage of keeping the system clean.

The explicit `language_level` ([what is `language_level`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54900723/5769463)) is needed in order to prevent warnings.

---

If you use a virtual environment and install you cython-package via `setup.py` (or a similar workflow), you need [to make sure that `*.pxd` files are also included into installation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules), i.e. your setup-file needs to be augmented with:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
# usual stuff for cython-modules here
...

kwargs = {
      # usual stuff for cython-modules here
      ...

      #ensure pxd-files:
      'package_data' : { 'my_module': ['*.pxd']},
      'include_package_data' : True,
      'zip_safe' : False  #needed because setuptools are used
}

setup(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although mentioned earlier, the easiest way is to change the **cdef** declaration for **cpdef** :

```
cpdef double foo(double a) nogil:
    return 3. * a
```

No need to change anything else. For most purposes they are practically the same, cpdef has slightly more overhead but plays nicer with inheritance, see [details here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html):

> The directive cpdef makes two versions of the method available; one
> fast for use from Cython and one slower for use from Python. Then:
>
> This does slightly more than providing a python wrapper for a cdef
> method: unlike a cdef method, a cpdef method is fully overridable by
> methods and instance attributes in Python subclasses. It adds a little
> calling overhead compared to a cdef method.

Comment: And if my cdef function has the following signature: cdef foo(double* a)?

Comment: Then you can use your answer, which is still correct :)