# What does language_level in setup.py for cython do?

Tags: cython

If I set `language_level=2` in `ext_modules = cythonize(extensions, language_level=2)`, what does that change? Is it just that the code I have written should be interpreted as Python2?

Is the end result exactly the same?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html?highlight=Language_level#cythonize-arguments) that's not a direct argument to cythonize, but could be passed as a compiler directive.

Comment: Yes - See [@ead's answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603628/how-to-specify-python-3-source-in-cythons-setup-py)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Building a cython extension is a two-step proccess:

1. creating the `foo.c`-file from `foo.pyx` file using PythonX+cython-module. `X` could be here 2.7, 3.7 or whatever version you prefer.
2. creating the corresponding so-file (or pyd on Windows) with help of compiler and includes of PythonY and corresponding shared library. Here `Y` doesn't have to be `X`, but in most cases `Y` and `X` are the same.

The resulting extension can be used with PythonY (it doesn't play a role what `X` was).

However, there is still the question: In which Python-version was the original `pyx`-file written? If `language_level` is not set, current Cython-versions assume that the pyx-file was written in the version `2` (btw. this is not the case for IPython-%%cython-magic, where the version with which the file `foo.c` is cythonized).

This behavior will change in the future, this is the reason you see the somewhat irritating warning, if you build with `cython>=0.29`:

> /Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not
> set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File:
> XXXXXX.pyx
> `tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)`

So you [can explicitly set the `language_level`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34603628/5769463), so that your extension has the same behavior independent of the Cython-version with which it was cythonized.

For some examples of different behavior see, the following example.

Using `language_level=3`:

```py
%%cython -3
print("I'm", "not a tuple")
print(5/4)
```

results in

```
I'm not a tuple
1.25
```

but using `language_level=2`:

```py
%%cython -2
print("I'm", "not a tuple")
print(5/4)
```

results in

```
("I'm", 'not a tuple')   # yet a tuple!
1                        # integer division in Python2!
```

Obviously the above are only two examples, there are much more differences (e.g. `str` & `unicode` stuff).

---

One of other notable differences is that [Python3 disables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12172791/5769463) [implicit relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/5769463), that means inside of a package, we no longer cimport using implicit relative import

```py
# works with language_level=2
cimport other_local_cymodule
```

but use explicit relative import

```py
 # works with language_level=3,3str
 from . cimport other_local_cymodule
```

or absolute import

```py
 # works with language_level=3,3str
 cimport package.other_local_cymodule
```

---

In general I would try to avoid mixing different `language_level` and Python-interpreter-version, as it can lead to counter-intuitive behavior.

For example in the following example mixing `language_level=2` and Python3:

```py
%%cython -2
def divide2(int a, int b):
    return a/b

def divide3(a, b):
    return a/b

>>> divide2(2,3), divide3(2,3)
# (0, 0.66666666)
```

For the function `divide2` Cython can ensure the "right" Python2-behavior, but how the division is performed depends on the behavior of `int`-object, which has the normal Python3-behavior.