# Cython prange with an array of string

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython

I'm trying to use prange in order to process multiple strings.
As it is not possible to do this with a python list, I'm using a numpy array.

With an array of floats, this function works :

```
from cython.parallel import prange
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray as ar

cpdef func_float(ar[np.float64_t,cast=True] x, double alpha):
    cdef int i
    for i in prange(x.shape[0], nogil=True):
        x[i] = alpha * x[i]
    return x
```

When I try this simple one :

```
cpdef func_string(ar[np.str,cast=True] x):
    cdef int i
    for i in prange(x.shape[0], nogil=True):
        x[i] = x[i] + str(i)
    return x
```

I'm getting this

```
>> func_string(x = np.array(["apple","pear"],dtype=np.str))
  File "processing.pyx", line 8, in processing.func_string
    cpdef func_string(ar[np.str,cast=True] x):
ValueError: Item size of buffer (20 bytes) does not match size of 'str object' (8 bytes)
```

I'm probably missing something and I can't find an alternative to str.
Is there a way to properly use prange with an array of string ?

Comment: Does this work if you change `prange` to `range`?

Comment: @DavidW I want to keep prange. Changing to range has no effect.

Comment: Which Python/Cython version are you using? I'm surprised your code compiled at all, because `str(i)` should create a Python-object which shouldn't be possible without gil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the fact, that your code should fail when cythonized, because you try to create a Python-object (i.e. `str(i)`) without gil, your code isn't doing what you think it should do.

In order to analyse what is going on, let's take a look at a much simple cython-version:

```
%%cython -2
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray as ar

cpdef func_string(ar[np.str, cast=True] x):
    print(len(x))
```

From your error message, one can deduct that you use Python 3 and the Cython-extension is built with (still default) [`language_level=2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54900723/5769463), thus I'm using `-2` in the `%%cython`-magic cell.

And now:

```
>>> x = np.array(["apple", "pear"], dtype=np.str)
>>> func_string(x)    
ValueError: Item size of buffer (20 bytes) does not match size of 'str object' (8 bytes)
```

What is going on?

**`x` is not what you think it is**

First, let's take a look at `x`:

```
>>> x.dtype
<U5
```

So `x` isn't a collection of unicode-objects. An element of `x` consist of 5 unicode-characters and those elements are stored contiguously in memory, one after another. What is important: The same information as in unicode-objects stored in a **different** memory layout.

This is one of numpy's quirks and how `np.array` works: every element in the list is converted to an unicode-object, than the maximal size of the element is calculated and dtype (in this case `<U5`) is calculated and used.

**`np.str` is interpreted differently in cython code (`ar[np.str] x`) (twice!)**

First difference: in your Python3-code `np.str` is for `unicode`, but in your cython code, which is cythonized with `language_level=2`, `np.str` is for `bytes` (see [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types)).

Second difference: seeing `np.str`, Cython will interpret it as array with Python-objects (maybe it should be seen as a Cython-bug) - it is almost the same as if `dtype` were `np.object` - actually the only difference to `np.object` are slightly different error messages.

With this information we can understand the error message. During the runtime, the input-array is checked (before the first line of the function is executed!):

1. expected is an array with python-objects, i.e. 8-byte pointers, i.e. array with element size of 8bytes
2. received is an array with element size 5*4=20 bytes (one unicode-character is 4 bytes)

thus the cast cannot be done and the observed exception is thrown.

**you cannot change the size of an element in an `<U..`-numpy-array**:

Now let's take a look at the following:

```
>>> x = np.array(["apple", b"pear"], dtype=np.str)
>>> x[0] = x[0]+str(0)
>>> x[0]
'apple'
```

the element didn't change, because the string `x[0]+str(0)` was truncated while written back to `x`-array: there is only place for 5 characters! It would work (to some degree, as long as resulting string has no more than 5 characters) with `"pear"` though:

```
>>> x[1] = x[1]+str(1)
>>> x[1]
'pear0'
```

---

Where does this all leave you?

- you probably want to use `bytes` and not `unicodes` (i.e. `dtype=np.bytes_`)
- given you don't know the element size of your numpy-array at the compile type, you should declare the input-array `x` as `ar x` in the signature and roll out the runtime checks, similar as done in the Cython's ["depricated" numpy-tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html#adding-types).
- if changes should be done in-place, the elements in the input-array should be big enough for the resulting strings.

All of the above, has nothing to do with `prange`. To use `prange` you cannot use `str(i)` because it operates on python-objects.