# cython report bug: expected an identifier

Tags: cython

I am using `cython` to convert `py` file to `pyd` file.

My test code is:

```
# funcA.py
class Window:

    def exec(self):
        pass
    pass
```

And the `setup.py` file is:

```
#setup.py
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('funcA', ['funcA.py']),
]

setup(
    name='App',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    include_dirs=["App"],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

After `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, a bug is reported:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

class Window:

    def exec(self):
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

funcA.py:4:8: Expected an identifier
building 'funcA' extension
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IApp -ID:\Anaconda3\envs\work\include -ID:\Anaconda3\envs\work\Includ
e "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /TcfuncA.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\funcA.obj
funcA.c
funcA.c(1): fatal error C1189: #error:  Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

But, if I replace the `funcA.py` to:

```
#new funcA.py
class Window:

    pass
```

Everything is OK.

Why `exec` function would couse this bug?

Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

------------- update --------------------------------

Thanks @DavidW's suggestion.

The solution is adding `#cython: language_level=3` on the top of script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what Cython version you're using (you don't say...) Cython defaults to Python 2 behaviour. [In Python 2 `exec` was a keyword, so cannot be used as a function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3).

Either:

- pick a different function name,
- put Cython in Python 3-like mode [by setting `language_level` to `3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900723/what-does-language-level-in-setup-py-for-cython-do). Bear in mind this may change some other things (e.g. `print`, the scope of list comprehensions, ...)
- Use Cython 3 alpha version where it does default to Python 3 semantics by default.

Comment: Thank you very much. Setting `language_level` to 3 works.